# What is the probability that an incoming email containing the word w is spam?

Tags: probability, permutations

Suppose that the probability that an incoming email is a spam is $p(S)$, that the probability that the word w occurs in the subject line of the spam is $p(w)$,

and that $q(w)$ is the probability that the word $w$ occurs in the subject line of an email that is not a spam.

What is the probability that an incoming email containing the word $w$ is spam ?

I am confused in using conditional probability and not gaining any progress in this

Comment: Please mention about your thoughts regarding the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let define two events.

**Event 1:** Name it as $S$. This event represents whether a mail is a spam.

**Event 2:** Name it as $W$. This event represents whether w occurs in the subject line of the email.

Now the given information represents the following probabilities-
$$P(W|S)=p(w), P(S) =p(s),\ P(W|S^C)=q(w).$$

Now, we have to find the probability of the event- $S|W.$

Apply **Bayes' Theorem**-
$$P(S|W)=\frac{P(W|S)}{P(W)}=\frac{P(W|S)}{P(S)P(W|S)+P(S^c)P(W|S^c)}=\frac{p(w)}{p(s)p(w)+(1-p(s))q(w)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

There are for kinds of mail with the following respective probabilities:

- Spam with w: $p(S)p(w)$
- Spam without w: $p(S)(1-p(w))$
- Ham with w: $(1-p(S))q(w)$
- Ham without w: $(1-p(S))(1-q(w))$

Thus the probybility that w occurs in an aritrary mail is $p(S)p(w)+(1-p(S))q(w)$ and the probability that such a mail is in fact spam is
$$ \frac{p(S)p(w)}{p(S)p(w)+(1-p(S))q(w)}$$